# Laravel 5.5 - how to check if the query builder has inserted data successfully?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

How can I check if [the query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts) has inserted my data successfully?

```
    $result = $this->database->table('user')->insert([
        'uuid' => $uuid,
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'created_on' => $createdOn
    ]);

    print_r($result); // 1
```

But if I provide an empty array:

```
    $result = $this->database->table('user')->insert([]);

    print_r($result); // 1
```

I also get the same result.

So what is the best way to know if a data is inserted?

Comment: Please don't chain the last function `insert`, do it like: `$result = $db->insert([]);` where `$db = $this->database->table('user');`

Comment: @MohamedKawsara why is that?

Comment: My bad, you are right, I thought it's a save() and chain will return the object itself, *sorry*, unfortunately, since you are using `insert()` and not save(), you can't actually tell! because it's like this `if(empty($values)) return true;` you can check the line:column `2092:9` from the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insertGetId` method and then check the inserted `id` exists:

```
$id = $this->database->table('user')->insertGetId($query);
if( empty($id) ){    
   Log::error('Failed to insert data row into database.');
}
```

Comment: tested but no difference. but i get a 0 when it actually inserts ok.

Comment: Does `user` table has primary key setted ?

Comment: Well `insertGetId()` returns auto-incrementing primary key, like mysql `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. And if you are using PostgreSQL check red note in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)